# Reactor, Boolean by value Returned object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I want to create a new collection based on the model name. If there is a collection with the same name, then the existing one is returning. If not, the newly created collection returns. I'm using ReactiveCrudRepository. I'm new to reactive. I get this error in the underlying code. What should I do?

```
public Mono<MongoCollection<Document>> constructDBCollection(String modelName) {
        return reactiveMongoOperations.collectionExists(modelName)
                .flatMap(exists -> exists ? reactiveMongoOperations.getCollection(modelName) : reactiveMongoOperations.createCollection(modelName, CollectionOptions.empty()
                .size(1024 * 1024)
                .capped()));
    }
```

> Error The type of flatMap(java.util.function.Function>) is
>   erroneous DBCollectionFactory.java    /src/main/java/com/jagger/obls/factory/DBCollectionFactory.java:26
>
> Error incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
>   (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression       bad
>   type in conditional expression
>   com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoCollection
>   cannot be converted to reactor.core.publisher.Mono)   DBCollectionFactory.java    /src/main/java/com/jagger/obls/factory/DBCollectionFactory.java:26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the javadoc, `getCollection` actually returns the `MongoCollection<Document>`, not a `Mono` of it. So wrapping this call in a `Mono.just(reactiveMongoOperations.getCollection(modelName))` should do it.